# Can't set the header after they are sent to client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an error "Can't set the header after they are sent to client" when basic authentication and jwt token are not provided in incoming request.

I am getting this error as i am not able to stop node.js from going to `verifyJWTToken` function when `verifyBasicAuth` fails.

How do i instruct nodejs not to run `verifyJWTToken` function when `verifyBasicAuth` already returned a response?

My route code -

```
app.post('endpointurl', verifyBasicAuth, verifyJWTToken, postOperation);
```

Comment: please show your code. without it, we can't do much.

Comment: I think my question is pretty simple.How do i instruct nodejs not to execute verifyJWTToken function when verifyBasicAuth function already returned a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the implementation of `verifyJWTToken` middleware is accessible. Add a check if response headers are already sent.

I have assumed the implementation as you have not shared any code.

```
var verifyJWTToken = function(req,res,next){
    if(!res.headersSent){
      // response headers are not set yet, execute verification  
    }
    else{
      next(); //proceed to next middleware with out sending any response
    }
}
```